# How to remove punctuation in python?

Tags: python, string, punctuation

I've a problem:

E.x. I have a sentence

```
s = "AAA? BBB. CCC!"
```

So, I do:

```
import string
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
s = [w.translate(table) for w in s]
```

And it's all right. My new sentence will be:

```
s = "AAA BBB CCC"
```

But, if I have input sentence like:

```
s = "AAA? BBB. CCC! DDD.EEE"
```

after remove punctuation the same method as below I'll have

```
s = "AAA BBB CCC DDDEEE"
```

but need:

```
s = "AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE"
```

Is any ideas/methods how to solve this problem?

Comment: @9769953 Sorry! It's my mistake! Of course I want to remove it all! (edit)

Comment: Why not just s = [ w if w not in string.punctuation else ' '  for w in s]

Comment: @Luv that would result in the last case where if a punctuation is immediately  between two words it would merge the words

Comment: @casualcoder no, because you replace the punctuation with a ' ' space

Comment: @Luv  mb, i did not see the space in `' '`, then you have a case where you will sometimes have two spaces between words

Answer (score 8):

[string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) contains following characters:

> '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'

You can use translate and maketrans functions to map punctuations to empty values (replace)

```
import string

'AAA? BBB. CCC! DDD.EEE'.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

Output:

```
'AAA BBB CCC DDDEEE'
```

Comment: I think he asked for different output

Comment: Depending on the language, it will leave many punctuation and special chars behind.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
import re

input_str = "AAA? BBB. CCC! DDD.EEE"
output_str = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', input_str)
print output_str
```

> 'AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE'

Comment: Same problem as the one @casualcoder pointed above. multiple spaces between words.

Comment: Use this to cover some edge cases `r'[^\w]+(\s+|$)'`, and add `.strip()` otherwise you'll have an extra space if the last word ends with a punctuation character.

Comment: Obs.: in this way you remove special characters like ß and also the ones with graphic signals, like ü,ú,.. so depending on your language is not a good option.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it like this:

```
punctuation = "!@#$%^&*()_+<>?:.,;"  # add whatever you want

s = "AAA? BBB. CCC!" 
for c in s:
    if c in punctuation:
        s = s.replace(c, "")

print(s)

>>> "AAA BBB CCC"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import re

" ".join(re.split('\W+', s))
```

That splits the string on all non-word characters, then joins the individual substrings by single spaces.

Comment: Actually, in Python, \W includes word forming characters as well as non-word characters.

Comment: @Andj Interesting. But what do you mean by "word forming characters" here?

Comment: the Unicode definition of `\w` is  `[\p{alpha}\p{gc=Mark}\p{digit}\p{gc=Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`. The re module defines it as most of \p{alpha}, all of \p{digit} and one of \p{gc=Connector_Punctuation}. So all Marks and  Join Controls are stripped.

Comment: Take pattern `pattern = re.compile(r'[^\w]', re.U)` and then `re.sub(pattern, "", text)` using `text='မြန်မာစကား'` you would get the result `'မနမစက'`. All medial consonants and dependent vowels are striped out. Personally, I would consider medial consonants and dependent vowels as word forming characters. Also try `text = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", "français")` this results in `'francais'`. So, combining diacritics are treated by re as non-word forming characters.

Comment: Obviously, you could have had `pattern = re.compile(r'[\W]')` instead of `pattern = re.compile(r'[^\w]'`. The results are the same. Also, the regex flag `re.U` doesn't really add anything on my plaform.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `str.strip` and a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
from string import punctuation

s = "AAA? BBB. CCC! DDD.EEE"

def cleanString(strval):
    return "".join(" " if i in punctuation else i for i in strval.strip(punctuation))

s = " ".join(cleanString(i) for i in s.split())
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_string = "AAA? BBB. CCC! DDD.EEE"
    result = "".join((char if char.isalpha() else " ") for char in test_string)
    print(result)


Result: AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD EEE
```

Comment: This will add extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
exclude.remove(".")
doc = "AAA? BBB. CCC! DDD.EEE"
for punctuation in exclude:
    doc = doc.replace(punctuation,"")
doc = doc.replace("."," ")
doc = doc.split()
print(" ".join(doc))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know not everyone has this situation, but I am writing an internationalized app and it's a bit heavier lift. This is what I have come up with:

[Edited to add 'import regex'] - Thanks Andj

```
import regex

random_string = "~`!ќ®†њѓѕў‘“ъйжюёф №%:,)( ЛПМКё…∆≤≥“™ƒђ≈≠»"

clean_string = regex.sub( r'[^\w\s]', '', random_string )

print( clean_string )
```

Result is:

```
ќњѓѕўъйжюёф  ЛПМКёƒђ
```

This works with a wide range of alphabets and special characters in many languages. I've tested it on several languages with every special character and a few regular characters on that keyboard. Still need to strip out a few special markers this won't detect.

Straightforward but powerful. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: if you are using `r'[^\w\s]'` as a pattern use the regex module, rather than the re module. Your regex substitution will strip out important word forming characters for many languages and scripts. `\w` and `\W` with the re module are quite dangerous if your code needs to be able to support any language.

Comment: please elaborate. one of features of the app i'm writing is to reduce errors in file name generation.

Comment: it is a complex topic, and it really depends on the languages and writing systems/scripts you need to support. For instance re's \w metacharacter supports a most (but not all) of \p{alpha}, all of \p{digits}, only one of \p{gc=Connector_Punctuation}, none of \p{gc=Mark}, and none of \p{Join_Control}. The core issue is around Marks. All marks are treated as non word forming characters. So combining diacritics are not word forming characters, dependent vowels in South Asian and south-east Asian script, Arabic marks, etc ... all not matched by \w. NFD data has big problems with \w.

Comment: Take a file name like kɔ̈ɔ̈r.png (i chose it because i do have a file of that name on my computer). It uses two combining diacritics. It is the same in NFC, NFKC, NFKC_CF, NFD, and NFKD. Your regex pattern above would make the following transform: kɔ̈ɔ̈r -> kɔɔr. More problematically, for a file မြန်မာစာ.md, မြန်မာစာ would transform to မနမစ, i.e completely unrecognisable give the original filename. If you are restricted to LCG life is somewhat easier, but NFD or NFKD will cause grief.

Comment: Thanks @Andj. It's not at a certain what languages this app will be used with. The regex module is a simple fix. There is probably still something lurking under the covers. Only time will tell.

Comment: if you want to future proof yourself, try the regex module's implementation of \w and \W. Better for your purposes than try the re module.With Python the devil is in the detail. Unfortunately the detail doesn't end up in the documentation.

Comment: That is precisely what I have done. If I understand you correctly, I have simply replaced 're' with 'regex'. I have looked a little into regex and it seems a better implementation.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, not all of my comment was submitted. The missing piece of the comment was that you also need to be aware that regex is likely to be using a different version of Unicode to re. The difference between re and regex implementation of \w and \W, and whether for your usage scenario would benefit from the regex version of \w, a tailoring somewhere between re and regex, or whether you need a superset containing the regex \w and some additional characters.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use regex with  \w and add hyphen and period to it.

Comment: I work with multilingual data, potentially in any language. I tend to use virtual environments targeted at a specific version of Python. That means I am also targeting a specific version of Unicode, since each version of Python is using a different version of Unicode. To ensure the widest compatibility and handle edge cases, I install the most recent version of regex build against the version of Unicode I am using. If the version of icu4c is more recent, I use UnicodeSet notations to allow me to target the character repertoire of a specific version of Unicode.

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. I have just started working with multilingual text. The text will be added into a database, but is primarily used for naming files instead of users being forced to use ASCII (not even unicode) text. My filename "cleanser" has to remove any punctuation and leave plausible text (Unicode) to be used in the file name. Training people to use ASCII became increasingly unrealistic as we delve deeper into non-latin scripts so I was tasked with writing a full-blown video file management system for our workflow.

Comment: I have also backburnered creating a venv for my app distro so I can depend on availability of third-party software. Eventually, that beast will rear it's ugly head and I will have to deal with it.

Comment: hope your project goes well. I know for Catalan and Valencian support I had to add punt volant as a word forming character rather than as punctuation. Over time, you build up more and more exceptions as new languages. But often I am on the edge, some of the code relates to Unicode proposals, so working with characters we are still trying to get added to Unicode.

Comment: Thanks! So far so good. tested it on a low-hanging-fruit project for Russian. Went pretty well except they kept switching keyboards from Cyrillic to Latin. Just remember C != C

Comment: test against \p{Cyrillic} if you expect everything in Cyrillic. You can either just throw an error, a warning or transliterated Latin to cyrillic.

Comment: If I understand your comment, \p{Cyrillic} is a literal expression for the regex module. I'll have a look. But this gets sticky as we have several languages now.

Comment: Yes is an expression for regex, some engines also use the Posix notation [:Cyrillic:]. It can also be used in Unicode Set notation. If I understand your use case, some filenames will have characters from incorrect script de to keyboard change. It's difficult to address. The trick is detecting the ones in this situation. Then determine the dominant script (the most frequently occurring) and use that as your default. In the example you gave, you could have had three scripts in filename: Latin, Cyrillic and Common (numbers, punctuation, etc.)

Comment: I've started a q/a thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75847941/regex-for-unicode-text-to-filter-characters-out-for-file-names