# regex for unicode text to filter characters out for file names

Tags: regex, unicode

The Problem:
I am working on a file management web app targeted at book translations. In particular, this app collects meta data about fragments of the translation. The meta data includes book name, chapter name/number, page, paragraph range and translator name. So far so good.

This app is also fully localized. Any text displayed to users will come from translated language files. The meta data will be used for file names. Languages being the things they are, there are many scripts that have certain non-letter diacritics and punctuation that might be detrimental in filenames. One such mark that comes to mind is an apostrophe.

The final use-case does not need to be Shakespeare. I am willing to sacrifice exactness so long as an elementary level of legibility is maintained.

I am using Python for the server. Regex is used to filter out unwanted characters for the file name, therefore the answer might be provided by anyone that knows regex.

My current implementation is:

```
import regex

random_string = "~`!ќ®†њѓѕў‘“ъйжюёф №%:,)( ЛПМКё…∆≤≥“™ƒђ≈≠»"

clean_string = regex.sub( r'[^\w\s]', '', random_string )

print( clean_string )
```

which results in:

```
ќњѓѕўъйжюёф  ЛПМКёƒђ
```

Seems to solve the problem and should get me a good ways down the road, but as our work progresses into regions with unusual scripts, we might encounter scripts that would break this implementation.

Is this the best solution given the goals?

Is there a better solution?

---

Based on a suggestion by @Destroy666, I would also be grateful for some real-world script examples from some languages that would stress test any solution.

The Solution:
Basic legibility of filtered file names to nationals should be achievable even if a few diacritics or punctuation marks are left out.

I am looking to "future- and bullet-proof" this feature in the app. This app is a little technical to install and update (which is also something I am also working on). The people working on these projects are newly trained and not usually very technical.

The solution should be reasonably robust without being needlessly complex. One interesting suggestion was made regarding the use of such regex expressions that contain '\p{Cyrillic}' for Russian. I am not adverse to this, but the "Cyrillic" string must be configurable based on local language of the project. Are there enough such script strings to cover all scripts?

Since my implementation is Python, I prefer a Python-based solution. But open to any regex (or other) implementation that solves the problem.

---

Loosely based on a suggestion by @Destroy666, I would also be grateful for some real-world script examples from some languages that would stress test any solution.

Kudos to @Andj

Comment: So you want to keep letters, diacritics and whitespaces only?

Comment: Which OS are you targeting that has trouble with `'` in filenames? Even your random_string example is a fine filename on Mac (it's not even hard to work with). If this is Windows-specific, you'll just need to strip characters that Windows has a problem with. I don't think there's any answer here because it relies on a very personal meaning of "clean." You will need to strictly define what you mean by that in order to build a filter. But I'd start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words, which provides a good list of possible problems to remove.

Comment: Target OS is another issue. This regex lives in a configuration file and can be adapted on an as-needed basis.

Comment: These files might be transfered between operating systems. Windows is the squeaky wheel in that scenario. Does an elementary list of no-fly characters as per the wiki page solve my problems with filenaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library, you can use this:

```
[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N} ]
```

to make sure you match all kind of Unicode letters, all marks (diacritics), digits and regular spaces as `\s` isn't really what you should use since e.g. `\n` isn't allowed in at least Windows file names - you could convert all the rest to regular spaces first. See [Unicode regex info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for the possible `\p` sets.

But that won't keep e.g. apostrophes mentioned by you that are valid characters important for some book titles. To not exclude these, you'd need to add them to regex one by one as there's no simple way to define characters that are valid for file names and also "clean looking". This includes some popular characters in book titles, for example:

```
[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N} ',.()-]
```

As for purposes of making sure the file name is not incorrect, I think a much better option is to use a sanitizer like [pathvalidate](https://github.com/thombashi/pathvalidate#sanitize-a-filename) library, e.g.:

```
from pathvalidate import sanitize_filename

filename = sanitize_filename(filename)
```

It will make sure to strip only necessary characters. You can also choose to only validate for specific platforms if needed.

You could also always sanitize first to make sure no disallowed characters are kept and then use e.g. `\p{Pd}` for Unicode dash punctuation, `\p{Pc}` for underscores and alike, `\p{Pi}`, `\p{Pf}` for any kinds of quotes, etc. which should match the "clean" criteria.

Comment: Can you provide script use cases that stress test your solution?

Comment: That's a really unexpected request considering you're the one coding a book-related application, not me - you should test how something performs with your data, which I don't have access to. It's also not related to the initial question in any way, so not sure what exactly you expect from me.

Comment: I understand your point of view. However, we are wandering into the unknown and I am asking for people with that kind of experience to provide a solution that will guide us there safely. In other words, I cannot predict the future and have no use cases for the unknown. But if someone has a solution that answers to this issue, I would be grateful. It relates directly to the initial question: "Basic legibility of filtered file names to nationals should be achievable even if a few diacritics or punctuation marks are left out."

Comment: Ok, I see. I don't have experience with this type of app, so I can't help further with that request. You could wait for other answers that show stress testing examples but that is much faster and accurate when done by yourself. And what I wrote about "clean looking" files still applies - without knowing exactly what that means, which is very subjective and opinion-based -  one website may want to do it cleaner, one faster, it's hard to say where exactly performance stops and UX starts. Unless you are cleaning tons of records at once, performance of a single regex shouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will await collection of more answers before applying anything. Also note that I have slightly modified the question. Look at the end of the question.

Comment: Here's another problem on this issue. We have a Russian pilot project using my app and it tries to verify the filename in the db == the one on disk. We find that two localized strings and are **visually identical** but sadly !=. Clearly this is due to different character encoding. After a couple days testing, we have a work around to avoid direct comparison of "utf-8" or "cp1252" encoded character strings. Is there any way to normalize these visually identical strings so they can be directly compared?

Comment: @horace this is a different question but there are normalization libs in Python, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize

Comment: Indeed it is. I might post a question on it. But I wanted to get your or Andyj's attention on it before posting. And you have given me a good idea to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The (non-re) `\w` metacharacter equates to `[\p{alpha}\p{gc=Mark}\p{digit}\p{gc=Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]` which covers most requirements.

The more problematic issues are the use of punctuation as word forming characters and defective input, i.e. characters from incorrect script entered when the user fails to change keyboard before typing.

For the punctuation you need to distinguish two scenarios, language orthographies that use punctuation as part of a word. An example of this would be the Catalan *punt volant* which is used in the official orthography, i.e. l·l.

For the user case: the ʻOkina (fakauʻa) use a modifier letter, which should work with the above regex metacharacter, but users often just use the apostrophe or a single quotation mark instead of the modifier letter. This is a more complex scenario to handle, but not uncommon occurrence, social media is full of examples of the way users accommodate alphabets when an appropriate, easy to use keyboard layout is unavailable at the time.

The question is to what extent you need to accommodate this scenario. If you are using the regex module I would be inclined to use a user configuration file, allowing the user to specify punctuation they wish to allow, appending it to a default pattern based on `\w` and other characters you need to support.

Maybe something like:

```py
pattern = f"[^\w\00B7{user_punctuation}]"
```

Adding any additional characters you know you need to support.

Wrt `\q{Cyrillic}`, `[:Cyrillic:]`, `\p{sc=Cyrillic}` and `\p{scx=Cyrillic}`, etc All scripts supported by the version of Unicode you are using, are supported by this either Perl, POSIX, or Unicode style script sets (depending on the regular expression engine being used): re, regex or PyICU.

Apostrophe, left single quotation mark, and right single quotation mark are specifically

Comment: For both ʻOkina and l·l - I'd be OK with stripping out the punt volant and modifier letters. The last sentence in your answer left me hanging. =)

Comment: Appears that it was truncated. I would be inclined to exclude apostrophe and quotation marks. Unless you explicitly exclude ʻOkina it will probably be included. Punt volant is your call. Most of the missing continuation was more about identification of scripts in a string and an idea around determining the dominant script in a string.